# how to append new background image without overriding in CSS

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to use two background image like this

CSS:

```
nav li { 
background bg1
}

li#abc {
background bg2
}
```

HTML:

```
 nav


ul
  li id="abc"
```

I know you can override by doing `li#abc { background bg1 bg2 }..` but I was wondering if you can just append the bg2?

Comment: If you know the height of bg1 you can offset the background of li#abc by that amount and give it repeat-x or no-repeat

Comment: You can't. You have to define both backgrounds unless you use a separate element positioned on top/below the first and have background transparency.